# ffmpeg - excerpt from a large video file, preserving its additional streams

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file that has a stereo audio track and two additional stereo streams of audio. I'll include the mediainfo details at the end. The closest I've come to being able to excerpt a portion of this large file, while keeping all of the streams, is this:

`ffmpeg -i output.mov -ss 1200 -map 0 -c copy -to 00:21:00 -map 0:1 -c:a copy -map 0:2 -c:a copy output_excerpt.mov`

This seems to give me a bunch of extra streams, though. What's a correct command to do this?

I was expecting four streams, one video, a second for the video's main audio, then two additional strems of 2channels each. This is what my command shows in mediainfo:

```
Complete name                            : output_excerpt.mov
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.02 (qt  )
File size                                : 492 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 68.8 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 29.970 FPS
Writing application                      : Lavf58.76.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422 HQ
Codec ID                                 : apch
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Source duration                          : 59 s 993 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 58.8 Mb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 540 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 5.043
Stream size                              : 421 MiB (85%)
Source stream size                       : 440 MiB (89%)
Writing library                          : Apple
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.470 System B/G
mdhd_Duration                            : 60025

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : sowt
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 11.0 MiB (2%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : sowt
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Source duration                          : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 10.1 MiB (2%)
Source stream size                       : 10.1 MiB (2%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 2
mdhd_Duration                            : 60008

Audio #3
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : sowt
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Source duration                          : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 10.1 MiB (2%)
Source stream size                       : 10.1 MiB (2%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 3
mdhd_Duration                            : 60008

Audio #4
ID                                       : 5
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : sowt
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 11.0 MiB (2%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 4

Audio #5
ID                                       : 6
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : sowt
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Source duration                          : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 10.1 MiB (2%)
Source stream size                       : 10.1 MiB (2%)
Default                                  : No
Alternate group                          : 5
mdhd_Duration                            : 60008
```

thanks for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

This seemns to work:

```
ffmpeg -i output2.mov -ss 1200 -map 0 -c copy -to 00:21:00 output_excerpt.mov
```

I guess it's simpler than i thought.